# How to deal with unfindable duplicates, as an asker?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently had a question closed as a duplicate [How to disable a clippy lint for a single line / block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402812/how-to-disable-a-clippy-lint-for-a-single-line-block)

To my mind it was reasonable, the docs did not explain how to do it, and the search did not bring up anything useful. After posting it got an upvote, a couple comments, and a useful answer.

However later it was closed as a duplicate. After seeing the answer to my question, I can  see how the answer to the other question also answers mine. However there was no way for me to have known that going in; I thought my issue was clippy specific, while that answer is concerned with compiler warnings and uses a slightly different syntax, so I would not have recognized it as an answer to my question even if my search had turned it up (it didn't).

This sort of thing has happened to me several times, where I can only see how something is a duplicate after I understand the answer to my own question, and then I see that well, yes there is a link there. Is this correct duplicate marking behavior as an effort to keep the site very clean? I feel that it makes it less searchable but I may be missing something important.

Comment: it's a +1 question..... you asked it, got some rep, then got pointed to the proper duplicate. Dupes are not a problem in and of themselves. They are a problem if the dupe WAS easy to find.

Comment: Duplicate questions are not a bad thing; it's just a way to make sure we keep all answers for the same problem in the same space.  Some duplicates will be downvoted if readers feel research wasn't done, but the act of closure is not negative.

Comment: and the site search gives a false impression of working, but it really doesn't. Google your question with "site:stackoverflow.com" in the end of the question for better answers.

Comment: @Patrice clearly you have a category in your head for this but I don't really know what you mean. If the dupe can't reasonably be found, the askers will ask the question again and again. Isn't the purpose to build up a database of easily searchable answers so people can find things?

Comment: But now, Richard, if someone looks for the dupe with the same terms YOU used, they'll find your question. And finding your question links to the dupe with the answer. So it's a good think your question is there. It's now a "signpost" to the "harder to find" dupe :)

Comment: Duplicates as signposts is one of the core principles of Stack Overflow as a whole, and it is our way to make problems with multiple possible terms to search visible on search engines, as well as ensure that no one gets the dreaded "Use the search! [closed]" message, which is one of the most frustrating things on old-school forums and Q&A sites.

Comment: @RichardRast assuming that at least some of people who ask *good duplicates* (not the once where Google/Bing for title instantly gives you an answer) will not rage-delete they questions it would improve chances to find the right one (duplicates are auto-followed for anonymous users - so anonymous users will instantly get best answer, authenticated users will need to click duplicate link which is not too hard) ... Note that after your question if someone asks another one with "How to disable a clippy lint for a single line / block" title it will likely get -10 score for "no research shown"

Comment: Okay I am now seeing the distinction between "closed, but retained as a resource" and "closed, to be deleted". I had thought all "closed" questions were considered bad, and to be deleted.

Comment: You can't ask or search for something you don't know. That's exactly why dupe mech was implemented. You do your best on your question using what you have. Search using my knowledge. In that there is no shame. Then someone with other knowledge came and tag it duplicate. That's a Win-Win! We have your valuable question using your word and understaing of the issue, poiting dirrectly to an other formulation and understanding of the issue. Any one having the same understanding as you will get directed to the answer.

Answer (score 25):

> However there was no way for me to have known that going in; I thought my issue was clippy specific, while that answer is concerned with compiler warnings and uses a slightly different syntax, so I would not have recognized it as an answer to my question even if my search had turned it up (it didn't).

For this case, this is fine; sometimes, dupes *can* prove difficult to find.  Fortunately for you, someone was able to track one down and let it provide a solution for you.

Dupes aren't *bad*.  They just mean that the question you're posing has already been asked and answered in another part of the site.  If your question is more generic, then it'll be preserved as what we refer to as a "sign post" for others to be able to find the answer in a simpler fashion, thus reducing the likelihood that someone else has the same experience you did.

Comment: Yup, dupes aren't inherently bad. It's the users who then make the asker *feel* bad by chastising them for not searching or otherwise stating or implying that the dupe target could have been easily found by anyone.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this correct duplicate marking behavior as an effort to keep the site very clean?

It's fine, there's nothing bad with it as you'll get your question answered well enough, no matter how good the original question matches with yours. It's the answers that count.

> I feel that it makes it less searchable but I may be missing something important.

No, it makes future research even better and more probable to get results. As already mentioned certain duplicates may serve as signposts for answers that grind down to the real reasons of a problem, not just the symptoms bubbled up in a question.

---

Without the background of experience it's sometimes hard to ask the right questions (or to google these), though the answers are there, and many of them are residing in the Stack Overflow Q&A repository.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say this situation is perfect. Your question will remain there as a reference, a redirect to the other question. That means that other people who think like you did, and also can't find that other question, will still be able to find yours and from there get to the answer.

Your question makes the answer easier to find.